# python how to search in multidimensional array / list

Tags: python, arrays, list, search, multidimensional-array

I cannot figure out how to search in the follow list/array (stored in self._map_commodities) and the data is obtained from JSON.

**The problem:
I want to locate "wood" in the array and return the "size" value related to it**

I have tried to use index(), but I cannot get it to work.
T

```
class MyClass1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._data = ''
        self.list_commodities = []
        self._map_commodities = []

    def create_commodity_market(self):
        for commodity in self._data['commodities']:
            self.list_commodities.append(commodity['id'])
            self._map_commodities.append(commodity)

    def from_json(self):
        import json
        self._data = json.loads('{"commodities":[{"id":"food","size":"1.0"},{"id":"wood","size":"1.0"},{"id":"ore","size":"1.0"},{"id":"metal","size":"1.0"},{"id":"tools","size":"1.0"}]}')


x = MyClass1()
x.from_json()
x.create_commodity_market()
print(x.list_commodities)
print(x._map_commodities)
####print(x._map_commodities.index("wood")) # I want it to print the size-value of the wood object
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What  output does this script return?

Comment: You need to provide us with _map_commodities method

Comment: ['food', 'wood', 'ore', 'metal', 'tools']
[{'id': 'food', 'size': '1.0'}, {'id': 'wood', 'size': '1.0'}, {'id': 'ore', 'size': '1.0'}, {'id': 'metal', 'size': '1.0'}, {'id': 'tools', 'size': '1.0'}]

I need a way to search/match id's (food, wood, ore, metal, tools) and return the "size" related to them. I know everyone has size: 1.0 but they could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dictionary is more suitable for what you're trying to do:

```
class MyClass1(object):

def __init__(self):
    self._data = ''
    self._map_commodities = {}

def create_commodity_market(self):
    for commodity in self._data['commodities']:
        self._map_commodities[commodity['id']] = commodity['size']

def from_json(self):
    import json
    self._data = json.loads('{"commodities":[{"id":"food","size":"1.0"},{"id":"wood","size":"1.0"},{"id":"ore","size":"1.0"},{"id":"metal","size":"1.0"},{"id":"tools","size":"1.0"}]}')


x = MyClass1()
x.from_json()
x.create_commodity_market()
print(x._map_commodities["wood"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is:

```
print next(y['size'] for y in x._map_commodities if y['id'] == 'wood')
```

Which will throw an `StopIteration` exception if none of your items have the id 'wood'.

More generally, add a method like this to `MyClass1`:

```
def size_from_id(self, id_name):
    try:
        return next(y['size'] for y in self._map_commodities if y['id'] == id_name)
    except StopIteration:
        return None
```

Then you can call `x.size_from_id('wood')`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return the specific value on your function :

```
def from_json(self):
        import json
        self._data = json.loads('{"commodities":[{"id":"food","size":"1.0"},{"id":"wood","size":"1.0"},{"id":"ore","size":"1.0"},{"id":"metal","size":"1.0"},{"id":"tools","size":"1.0"}]}')
        return self._data
```

Then use indexing to get the related `size` of a word.for example :

```
x = MyClass1()
d=x.from_json()
print d['commodities'][1]['size']
u'1.0'
```

Comment: "return elf._data" should be "return self._data"

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) to handle the data

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads('{"commodities":[{"id":"food","size":"1.0"},{"id":"wood","size":"1.0"},{"id":"ore","size":"1.0"},{"id":"metal","size":"1.0"},{"id":"tools","size":"1.0"}]}')
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data['commodities'])

# get the size of the row with id = 'wood'
size = df[df['id'] == 'wood']['size']
print size

# you can get the value alone, too
print size.values[0]
```